# How can i use DateTime.AddXXXX functions in a Linq-to-Entities query?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to use `AddMonths` in a query

```
List<Entities.Subscriber> items = (from s in context.Subscribers
                 where s.Validated == false && s.ValidationEmailSent == true && s.SubscriptionDateTime < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)
                 select s).ToList();
```

But I  recieve an error :

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime
>   AddMonths(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a
>   store expression.

Is there a way I can use this function inside my query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest fix to this is to work out the time limit once *before* using LINQ:

```
DateTime limit = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);

List<Entities.Subscriber> items = (from s in context.Subscribers
             where s.Validated == false && s.ValidationEmailSent == true && 
                                           s.SubscriptionDateTime < limit)
             select s).ToList();
```

Or more readably IMO:

```
var items = context.Subscribers
                   .Where(s => !s.Validated &&
                               s.ValidationEmailSent &&
                               s.SubscriptionDateTime < limit)
                   .ToList();
```

There's no benefit in using a query expression here, and explicit comparisons with `true` and `false` are ugly IMO (unless your properties are of type `Nullable<bool>` of course).

Comment: This is fine if your are working with DateTime.Now... but if you need to work with the value in s.SuscriptionDateTime adding months the answer of Ani is better.

Comment: @Romias: In that case it would be answering a different question :)

Comment: haha... you are right... I commented thinking in my problem :)

Answer (score 5):

Jon Skeet has already provided a simple fix, but if you want the `DateTime.Now.AddMonths` bit to run on the database, try the [`EntityFunctions.AddMonths`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412484.aspx) method.

This is a more general approach that is especially useful when you cannot replicate the expression cheaply or correctly on the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to:

```
 DateTime oneMonth = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)
    List<Entities.Subscriber> items = (from s in context.Subscribers
                     where s.Validated == false && s.ValidationEmailSent == true && s.SubscriptionDateTime < oneMonth
                     select s).ToList();
```

You have to do this because AddMonth is a .NET function that can't be translated into SQL by Linq to Entities. Perform the calculation in your code and then use the resulting datetime will work.